# Joint density function is not factorable means its not independent?

Tags: probability

I know that if a function f(x,y) is independent if it can be broken up into f(x)f(y), but is it independent if and only if it is factorable? Can something be factorable if it is not independent and vice versa?

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factorization of probabilities is the definition of independence. So if you have two events $A,$ $B,$ they are independent if and only if $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B).$ This yields the same statement for the joint CDF $P(X\le x , Y\le y) = P(X\le x)P(Y\le y)$ which then is seen equivalent to factorization of the joint PDF (if it exists) by differentiating.

However, don't think any type of factorization is equivalent to independence. For instance just because $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$ doesn't mean $X$ and $Y$ are independent (although the converse is assured). This is the famous "[uncorrelated does not imply independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelated_random_variables#Example_of_dependence_without_correlation)" caveat.